# Angular.js : ng-repeat OrderBy fails to order values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I am using Angular.JS to retrieve data from an object array passed from the server. Each object has an ID, a name and a position identifier that is used to order the objects in a table.

However, orderBy does not work: here is an example output by showing the positions.

[image]

Here is the code of list.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

and the JADE page:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title  Angular.js Test Page
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        script(src='/javascripts/angular.min.js')
        script(src='/javascripts/list.js')

    body(ng-app='myApp', ng-controller='myCtrl' ng-init='list= #{JSON.stringify(list)}')

        .col-lg-3
            table.table.table-bordered
                thead
                    tr
                        th User List
                tfoot(ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy: 'position' track by item.position")
                    tr
                        td {{item.position}}
```

Here is the list that gets passed:

```
 "list": [
    {
        "position": 5,
        "name": "Item 1",
        "id": 205690
    },
    {
        "position": 9,
        "name": "Item 2",
        "id": 15540
    },
    {
        "position": 12,
        "name": "Item 3",
        "id": 360640
    },
    {
        "position": 27,
        "name": "Item 4",
        "id": 325470
    },
    {
        "position": 7,
        "name": "Item 5",
        "id": 271670
    },
    {
        "id": 72850,
        "name": "Item 6",
        "position": 9196
    },
    {
        "id": 15080,
        "name": "Item 7",
        "position": 6863
    },
    {
        "id": 242550,
        "name": "Item 8",
        "position": 6864
    },
    {
        "id": 207490,
        "name": "Item 9",
        "position": 6865
    },
    {
        "id": 15060,
        "name": "Item 10",
        "position": 6862
    }
]
```

By all sources I checked, the ng-repeat syntax is correct.

Result is the same if I track by id, or remove track by; if I use OrderBy: '-position', position 9196 is put at the bottom (after '5').

Firefox console shows no warning or error at all!

Everything seems fine, so I am confused about what is going on. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: its working for me , https://jsfiddle.net/wu395o9k/

Comment: Weird-- your example works fine on jsfiddle. I removed the controller, and downloaded the latest angular.js release, disabled the css but still no change. Could it be a problem with the table?

Comment: Could you try orderBy: position track by item.position?
Meaning without the single quotes

Comment: I did that, and did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use tbody instead of tfoot ?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy:'position' track by item.position">
            <td>{{item.position}}</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I did it in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu395o9k/) and it works ...

Comment: Thanks! I am curious as of why it would behave like this, but I guess it's outside the scope of the question...

Comment: Maybe because a footer must be at the last row of the table. So as you order by position, the first element will be taken as footer and the other one as table body.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is with your angular version.

my code works perfect when its on angularjs 1.2.1 and doesn't work on angularjs 1.0.3.  see it for your self on this fiddle

```
 <div ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in test track by item.id">
        {{item.name}}
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>    


$scope.list = [
{
    "position": 5,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "id": 205690
},
{
    "position": 9,
    "name": "Item 2",
    "id": 15540
},
{
    "position": 12,
    "name": "Item 3",
    "id": 360640
},
{
    "position": 27,
    "name": "Item 4",
    "id": 325470
}
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Miqe/wqgkst7d/1/